# Автоматическое расширение блока

Tags: css3, html, css

Подскажите, что нужно ввести в файл css, чтобы при увеличении странички или уменьшении, размер блока подгонялся под экран, т.е. например, при уменьшении размера, блок сверху, который был как раз с обычным размером, уехал вверх, а внизу пусто, как подогнать при изменении разрешения экрана этот блок?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте % соотношение

width:100%

Comment: оно уже используется, нужно как раз, чтобы менялось оно при изменении разрешения, например, если оно больше нормы, процент в файле меняется @media или как-то так, может быть что-то с этим связано

Answer (score 0):

min-width и max-width + просто width:100% и будет тебе счастье! А для мобилы смотри [@media](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) и подобное в гугле